# What is the canonical way of checking if two objects are of one specific class

Tags: python, types, comparison-operators, isinstance

Is there a pythonic way to check if two objects are of one specific type? I suppose this is more of academic interest than actual code necessity.

Obviously using two `isinstance()` would work, and the triple equation does the trick as well, but I was wondering if there is a one-liner that would work and be pythonic as well.

```py
if type(obj1) == type(obj2) == MyClass:
    #DoSomething
```

since this is equivalent to

```py
if (type(obj1) == type(obj2)) and (type(obj2) == MyClass):
    #DoSomething
```

the left check will raise a PEP8 warning to use `isinstance()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you wanted which may be useful **as the number of objects increases in size** (*disclaimer: not worth it for 2 objects, probably worth it for 4+ objects*):

```py
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [1,2]
>>> all(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, list), [a,b]))
True
```

Docs: [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all), [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda)

Comment: Is this really better than using one `and`?

Comment: @Julien No, but as the number of objects you wanted to check grew in size: yes. I would much rather see this than see 15 `and` if you wanted to check 15 objects.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether you want to consider two objects to be of the same class if one is an instance of a subclass of the class you're looking for.

So for instance if you have `one = classA()` and `two = classB()`, where `classB` is a subclass of `classA`. Your first approach, where you had:

```
type(one) == type(two) == classA
```

will evaluate to `False`. But using `isInstance` like so:

```
isInstance(one, classA) and isInstance(two, classA)
```

will evaluate to `True`.

What that PEP8 is about is to warn you of a gotcha that is so common, it the Python folks decided that the programmer needed to be warned about it. It is almost always more useful to compare classes via `isInstance`, to the point where if the interpreter sees `type(one) == type(two)` it will assume that you're not intending to do the unusual thing, you're intending to do the more commonly useful `isInstance` comparison, but that you're doing it wrong.

Long story short, you're most likely going to want to use `isInstance`, but without knowing about your situation I can't say for absolutely certain that you don't want to use `type`.

Comment: In my specific case I actually makes no difference since the class has no subclasses. My surprise was more the PEP8 warning since, while I absolutely agree `isinstance` should be used most of the time, I could see cases where you would want to ensure that an object is of a specific class and not one of its subclasses.